# Calculate the brute force possibilites for a password

Tags: combinatorics

Exercise:

Calculate the possibilities for a password according to the following conditions:

- All passwords start with "pw";
- This is followed by either 2 or 3 digits (0-9);
- After which come 8 characters from the set {"p","x","f"}

For the digits I think that the solution is: 10^2 * 10^3.
I think that for the last condition 3^8 is the correct calculation, but I'm not sure on how to combine all of the conditions to one calculation.

Would be nice if someone could help me!

Comment: Just like third condition, calculate for the second condition. Calculate for $2$ digits and then for $3$ digits.

Comment: Hint: the passwords which have $2$ digits and the passwords which have $3$ digits are disjoint. That is, a password either has $2$ digits or $3$ digits.

Comment: and there is only one way for the first condition.

Comment: @MathLover Is this correct: 1 * 10^2 * 10^3 * 3^8 ?

Comment: No, for $2$ digits, it is $1 \times 10^2 \times 3^8$.

Comment: Similarly for $3$ digits and then add them.

Comment: @MathLover Ah yes I think that I do understand it now. Last try:
For the 2 digit password:
1 * 10^2 * 3^8 = 656100

For the 3 digit password:
1 * 10^3 * 3^8 = 6561000

Combined possibilities:
656100 + 6561000 = 7217100

Correct?

Comment: I have not checked your math, other than that yes it is correct.

Comment: @MathLover Alright then, it was the logic behind the 2 and 3 digits that caused the problems. Thanks for your help!